# JPA Query Methods: findTopX where X is a given (variable) number?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm creating a RESTful API. I need to to be able to send a number to the API specifying the amount of news items it needs to return.

I already looked for some things and according to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) it is possible to limit your results, but I can't find anything about how to make it variable. So my question is: Is this even possible to do or do I need to write my own custom query for this.

I already tried things like:
`Iterable<NewsItem> findTopAmountByOrderByDatetimeDesc(Integer amount);` where Amount would be filled in by the given Integer "amount", but maybe it is stupid to even think this would be possible although it would be a nice feature in my opinion.

What I have now (not variable, so it doesn't care about the given number):

NewsItemApi:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newsitems/amount",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

NewsItemRepository:

```java
Iterable<NewsItem> findTop2ByOrderByDatetimeDesc();
```

NewsItemApiController:

```java
public ResponseEntity<Iterable> getLastNewsItems(@NotNull @ApiParam(value = "amount of news items to return", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "amount", required = true) Integer amount) {
        return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(this.newsItemRepository.findTop2ByOrderByDatetimeDesc());
    }
```

Comment: May I know why it received a -1? It is lame giving it a -1 without letting know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create repository and use @Query annotation to make custom requests, something like this:

```
public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<News, Long> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM NEWS ODER BY FIELD_YOU_WANT_TO_ODER_BY DESC LIMIT ?1", nativeQuery = true)
  List<News> getLatestNews(Integer amount);
}
```

Comment: This won't work. If you're not ordering, the result can be random.

Comment: What prevents it from adding sorting? Its just an example, add sort desc or asc as you wish

Comment: I'm just sayin. There would probably be problems if someone doesn't know

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use `@Query`, something like:

```
@Query("select n from NewsItem n order by n.datetime desc limit :num", nativeQuery = true)
Iterable<NewsItem> findTopXByOrderByDatetimeDesc(@Param("num") int num);
```

Of course use `limit` keyword according to your database.